# Run Jenkins Job only when specified Git branches are merged

Tags: git, jenkins, githooks

I am trying to find a way to automatically trigger a Jenkins Job only when specific git branches are merged. For example if branch a, branch b and branch c are merged, then the jenkins job should be triggered. Is this possible? If so, could anyone please explain the process necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there is no way to launch build based on the source branch.
Jenkins knows nothing about it. Only if you have some extra git hooks it`s available.

For the destination branches.
If you use declarative pipeline you can use [when](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when) condition to manage your builds.

If you use a freestyle project you setup "[Strategy for choosing what to build](https://plugins.jenkins.io/git)"
By defining mask at the branch field in the build settings

Comment: Are you using Gerrit??

Comment: No. We use Gitlab and GitHub